# How to guarantee that TestNG in gradle adds the JDK to IntelliJ's classpath?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, testng

I am using the gradle plugin `idea` and added TestNG to the `dependencies` as:

```
testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
```

while defining TestNG in the test block

```
test {
    useTestNG()
}
```

When I synchronize Gradle in IntellJ now and try to add a test I get:

*TestNG could not be found in the project module*

Effectively I need to add it manually to the classpath of IntellJ and what is more, even after adding it, the dependencies in my test files cannot be resolved:

```
error: package org.testng does not exist
```

import static org.testng.Assert.*;

How should I approach this to fully automatize it?

---

It seems to work when I change `testCompile` into `compile`. I tried the same for JUnit. Same effect. How can that be? `testCompile` extends `compile`. Has this to do with where my test files are? How can I change their location with `sourceSets`?

Comment: I'm using that all the time in latest IntelliJ Ultimate and it works. So maybe you got an older version of Intellij/gradle plugin?

Comment: @Sebi I am using the Community Edition. If I change `testCompile` into `compile` it works, maybe that one is not detected properly?

Comment: Hi Mahoni, did you take a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087901/adding-gradle-depdencies-to-intellij-compiler-classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle is a bit like Maven: It expects to find your tests in `src/test/java`. This helps to split your tests from your actual source code, so that the tests won't get into the final jar.

`testCompile` does indeed extend `compile`, but that only mean, that every dependency from `compile` is also a dependency for `testCompile`, but not the other way!

To change your source sets, you can do something like this:

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        java { srcDir 'src/main/tests' }        
    }
}
```

If you want all code to be in the `src/main/java` folder, you need to exclude the specific packages:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java { exclude 'tests/** ' }
    }
    test {
        java { 
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            include 'tests/**'
        }        
    }
}
```

Here the tests package is only used for the tests, while the other packages are in the main program.

See also: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N12323